# Bokeh (Change color as it progresses)

Tags: python, bokeh

So i am trying to change the color of the square i.e. AssessmentReceived when it is not null.
The data is coming out of the database and there null values in it. So when a person submits an assessment we want to change the color else it remains the same.

Here is a piece of my code
def build_progress_chart(df, coursecode):

```
### Set up Data
source = ColumnDataSource(df)
x='DayOfCourseX'
AssessmentReceived = 'ReceivedDay'

### Plot lines
p.line(x=x, y='CurrentY', color=colors[0], legend_label='Your Progress', line_width=3, line_alpha=.7, source=source)
p.line(x=x, y='BenchmarkY1', color=colors[3], line_width=3, line_dash='dashed', legend_label='Model of Success', source=source)
p.line(x=x, y='BenchmarkY2', color=colors[3], line_width=3, line_dash='dashed', legend_label='Model of Success', source=source)
p.varea(x=x, y1='BenchmarkY1', y2='BenchmarkY2', color=colors[3], fill_alpha=.2, source=source)
#p.vbar(x=x, legend_label = 'Assessment Targets', width=1, bottom='AssessmentY1', top='AssessmentY2', fill_color=colors[1], fill_alpha=1, line_color='black', line_width=.5, source=source)
**if AssessmentReceived == None:
    p1 = p.square(x=x, y='AssessmentY', legend_label = 'Assessment Targets', size=10, color="Yellow", fill_alpha=1, source=source, hover_fill_color = colors[3],hover_fill_alpha = 1.0)
else:
    p1 = p.square(x=x, y='AssessmentY', legend_label = 'Assessment Targets', size=10, color="Black", fill_alpha=1, source=source, hover_fill_color = colors[3],hover_fill_alpha = 1.0)**
```

Comment: It is just showing black not yellow.

Comment: As expected you are plotting a black square on top of every yellow square.

Comment: So what should I do? if a person has submitted Assessment 1 then the square should be black and the other Assessments that he hasn't submitted should be yellow.

Comment: This code doesn't really make sense. First it has invalid syntax (`**if AssessmentReceived == None:`). Secondly `AssessmentReceived` is a constant string, it will never be `None`. Maybe you have a column called "AssessmentReceived" in your dataframe, and you want to color depending on it? You can probably use a [CategoricalColorMapper](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html#colors).

Comment: [CustomJSTransform](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/data.html#customjstransform) is another option if it's just two nan/non-nan colors. Or explicitly splitting the data up front for two `square` calls. Or using a CDSView and a filter